# Match newline between HTML tags using RegEx

Tags: html, regex, newline

I have random newline between continuous paragraph within `<p>`, `<span>` and other HTML tags that i would like to remove. Also within some of `<p>` tag i have a span tag which i also want on single line. Basically i want to have `<p>` and its corresponding `</p>` on the same line. I have included an example below.

Sample input:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempus semper nisl, id pellentesque massa ultricies quis.
Phasellus felis felis, commodo a eleifend quis, volutpat quis orci.
Phasellus tortor odio, pretium in feugiat id, viverra at arcu.
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer id feugiat sapien.</span>
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tempus semper nisl, id pellentesque massa ultricies quis. Phasellus felis felis, commodo a eleifend quis, volutpat quis orci. Phasellus tortor odio, pretium in feugiat id, viverra at arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer id feugiat sapien.</span>
```

**Update:**

Tool - Nothing specific (Notepad++ RegEx, perl, sed (**preferred**))

Language - HTML

Parser - None, just adopted a project from a fellow who added newline instead of word wrap

Comment: What tool/language are you using to process the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Answer (score 0):

The tool/language information is need to solve it.
In general you are using an editor or Perl Compatible Regular Expressions Syntax, it will be:

**In Komodo Editor** (Find and Replace Dialog)

```
Find:(\.)(\s+)(\w+)
Replace:\1 \3
```

**In Perl**

```
$content="<span>.....  </span>"; # your content
$content=~s/(\.)(\s+)(\w+)/$1 $3/g;
```